# How is thread safety guaranteed using immutable objects

Tags: thread-safety, immutability

According to Wikipedia, a thread safe code is guaranteed to be free of race conditions and after going through internet, it seems that immutable objects are inherently threadsafe and does not require any additional synchronization. However, I am not able to understand how is that possible. 
For example lets say I have an immutable class Counter.

```
    public class Counter{
       private final int counter;
       public Counter(int counter){
          this.counter = counter;
       }
       public int getCounter(){ return counter;}
       public Counter incrementCounter(){
          return new Counter(counter+1);
       }
     }
```

Now lets say I create an object of counter with value 0. Two threads simultaneously access the object with value 0, increments it and ends with two different objects of counter, both with value 1. But doesn't this causes race condition?? By using synchronized blocks, I will get a single object with counter value of 2 as expected but not using Immutable objects. Even though immutable objects are thread safe for reading but do they need external synchronization while writing?

Comment: You can't change immutable objects. That's the *definition* of an immutable object. What you're doing there is creating a *new* object, which is not thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the threads "just" increase the counter and keep the object for themself, there is no problem. A problem would be if the threads want to store the new object where the old 0-counter was (and this variable is not immutable)

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now.. Just for clarification, you mean to say that even though the counter class is thread safe, I will have to use synchronization if I wanted, lets say, the threads work on updated data

Comment: Yes. Sync is nessecary to write (or read and write) to/from the same variable.